# Freeze and unfreeze top row in excel with one macro

Tags: excel, vba

How would you freeze and unfreeze the top row in excel with just one macro?
As in, click the macro once to freeze the top row, and click it again to unfreeze?

Comment: your question shows no effort/research of your own!

Comment: This is a Q and A post. I posted the answer at the same time i posted the question

Comment: ref https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/fu2q2a/stackoverflow_and_coronavirus/

Answer (score 4):

To do this you need if / else condition that check whether top row is frozen or not. 
Code below does this and works on the assumption that you want to freeze row 1 - instead of the top currently VISIBLE row.
If you did want to freeze top VISIBLE row you would remove "Range("A2").Select" line.

```
Sub Freezetop()

' sets cell (current cell) to go back to later
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveCell

' if panes not already frozen (splitrow=1 means top row frozen) it freezes them
' going to a2 and back means that what gets frozen is top row of the sheet, NOT the top currently visible row
If Not ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1 Then
    Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = False
    .ScrollRow = 1
    .ScrollColumn = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
' uncomment the below if you want you current active row to go to top of page
'    .ScrollRow = r.Row
End With

' unfreezes panes if they were frozen already
Else: ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

End If

r.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Both codes to freeze and unfreeze top row:

```
Sub Freeze()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Active the sheet you want
        .Activate
        'To remove any panes
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
        'Select the second row
        .Rows("2:2").Select
        'Apple freeze
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

    End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub UnFreeze()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Active the sheet you want
        .Activate
        'Remove freeze
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The question posed is how to perform this in "just one macro"